# when I running a command in angular project than show error

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, server-side-rendering

**ng add @nguniversal/express-engine**

show error-
[image]

Skipping installation: Package already installed
Schematic input does not validate against the Schema: {}
Errors:

```
  Data path "" should have required property 'clientProject'.
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue is generally because of a version mismatch in your package.json file.

When I had faced this issue that time problem with one of my package `"@angular-devkit/build-angular"`, and when I have changed `"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.800.2" to "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.7.0".`

Then I ran the command npm install after deleting node_modules.It was working fine

Answer (score 0):

You have add project name with the above command. Something like below:

```
ng add @nguniversal/express-engine --clientProject  <Project Name>
```